# How can I pass files with vue.js 2?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <form method="post" :action="baseUrl+'/product/edit'" files="true">
            ...
            <input type="file" name="image">
            ...
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        ...
    }
</script>
```

In debug in my controller like this :

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    dd($_FILES);
}
```

It display empty array. Should it display array of uploaded file

Is it because the writing of `files = "true"` is incorrect?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that `files = "true"` is incorrect.

Send form-data encoded as "multipart/form-data".
It should look like that:

`<form method="post" :action="baseUrl+'/product/edit'" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: 'Files' => true is used in laravel. It does not seem to work inside the vue.js template. I combine Laravel and vue.js